# How to test a rest api with Zend?

Tags: testing, rest, zend-framework

I don't know how to make unit test of my rest controller. Here is my code :

```
public function testpostAction(){
    $this->dispatch('/chain');

    $this->request->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/json')          
                  ->setMethod('POST')
                  ->setPost(array(
                      'chain_name' => 'mychaintest'
                  ));   

    $this->assertAction('post'); ???

}
```

How I make a post?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you need but, if you want to make a POST call (http) to test your REST service, you can use `Zend_Http_Client`:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.client.html

Anyway, if this is for unit testing it will be more complicated, since you'll need your application (the current build being testet) to be live and accesible in the server. That depends on how you have configured your build environment.

There should be a staging (virtual) machine where the build is (automatically) deployed before tests are run. That machine should be visible to the machine runing the tests.

Hope this helped. Cheers!

Comment: Yes it is for unit testing. So I just want to make a post and after compare the result with assert method like that :$list = new Application_Model_DbTable_Chain();
  $entries = $list->fetchAll();  
  
  $this->assertSame(4, count($entries));

Comment: Well, the thing that you need to keep in mind is that you cannot call your REST service if it is not deployed in a server. Your build has to deploy the application to a test server and afterwards run the test suite against that live service.

Answer (score 0):

So, basically your question is how to emulate calling PUT and DELETE in your controller tests?
Since this apparently doesn't work:

```
$this->request->setMethod('PUT');
```

You can access both these actions with plain HTTP POST by providing _method parameter.

So to call PUT:

```
$this->request->setMethod('POST');
$this->dispatch('articles/123?_method=put');
```

To call DELETE:

```
$this->request->setMethod('POST');
$this->dispatch('articles/123?_method=delete');
```

More reading on how to deal with RESTful routing here - http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.rest